# Digital signal directly to the USB port

Tags: usb

I was wondering if it's possible using PC USB port as a logic analyser, without using protocol format.
Maybe some low level programming ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, is not possible USB is a complex protocol that requires at least identification of attached devices by a device class with that the operating system assigns specific kernel module / drivers cf http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb1.shtml